# Should this question about GPUs comparison be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, reopen-closed

As soon as I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56591071/which-one-is-the-better-option-for-workstation-using-gpu-for-python-calculations) (deleted now):

[image]

I knew there was going be people who will not read it and just blindly vote to close. Just in case, I made a comment that stated the relevant Stack Overflow rules as I understand them. However, despite this, the question quickly gained enough close votes, and currently stands one delete vote away from oblivion.

Specifically, it was closed as "primarily opinion-based"; yet there is nothing open to interpretation, it can all be benchmarked; except if some operations favour one of the options speedwise, and some other operations favour the other; in which case putting forth the details on such should be a perfectly good - and still objective - answer.

Do I understand the rules? Was this a question that should be deleted? If so, why? No-one commented to disagree with my reasoning, just silently voted to close. If not, what recourse is there?

(To be sure, I have no horse in this race. I am not affiliated with the asker in any way, and I do not have the sufficient familiarity with the hardware being discussed to offer my own answer. I am just wondering if my call was correct or not - and if not, why.)

Comment: it feels like something that should be asked at super user because of the hardware request but it is for programming and can be benchmarked

Comment: @TarickWelling: Exactly my thinking, though note my quote in the comment there: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**.". It is not for SuperUser, it is exactly suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: @BDL But it does have everything to do with programming. It might be underspecified, in which case a good course of action would have been to prompt the inexperienced user to describe exactly "what the user is doing", not close without comment. You could also close it with "not enough research", I guess; but it was closed as "primarily opinion-based", which it demonstrably is not. Also, the question doesn't ask "between GPUs and CPUs"; it asks about two GPUs, everything else being the same.

Comment: The question was deleted. (Kinda lame, considering there was an ongoing meta discussion). Maybe you could add a screenshot so users with less than 10k rep can see it?

Comment: @yivi: Done. And I agree, it's lame to delete a question which is currently discussed.

Answer (score 16):

This question doesn't look like a good fit for SO.

It has almost nothing to do with programming but with hardware. The question could also be "Which hardware should I buy to play game X" or "Which hardware should I buy for CUDA video processing".

Yes, the author seems to want to develop numpy code on that hardware, but the question itself is not related to a programming problem. Note, that also questions like "What is the best keyboard for writing code" or "What's the best chair to sit while programming" would be off-topic.

I disagree that the performance for CUDA can easily be benchmarked. It entirely depends on what the user is doing. Does he need a lot of calculation power, a high memory transfer speed? How is best even defined? 
If it's just about the Cuda cores, then why not read the spec of each hardware? This is not secret/hidden at all.

Hardware comparison is simply nothing SO is suited for or should handle. Especially because there are a lot of other sites on the web that already provide that data.

I can't exactly tell why primary opinion based was used as a reason (I would have entered a custom close reason), but the question should not be reopened just to get it closed with some other message.

Comment: The quote "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." strongly implies that "tools used primarily for programming" are on-topic. GPU is used primarily for programming, in context of CUDA.

Comment: "Does he need a lot of calculation power, a high memory transfer speed?" is easily addressed in an objective answer: "If you need a lot of calculation power, X is better. If you need a high memory transfer speed, you should go with Y." - a perfectly objective, and useful answer - and, most importantly, relevant to Stack Overflow. "If it's just about the Cuda cores, then why not read the spec of each hardware?" because as a beginner CUDA user, he might not know how to compare the speed of two units working in unison to the speed of one more powerful one, even knowing all the specs.

Comment: And my office keyboard is primary used for programming too. The "tools used primarily for programming" can be translated to "tools which are primarily used by programmers and have almost no other purpose". Examples would be IDEs, special development hardware, ... GPUs are not primarily used for programming. But feel free to disagree with me. Let's wait how the voting turns out.

Comment: but what if it was asked if a NVIDIA T4 was better than a NVIDIA card X. Those cards don't have another (consumer, e.g. gaming) purpose and will be used for programming.

Comment: Are you seriously implying that CUDA is a "general hardware" concern more than a programming one? It is in no way comparable to a chair, or a keyboard. With direct correlation to the speed of execution of code that presumably needs such speed, it is more comparable to a choice of algorithm (where "should I use BFS or DFS for X" is a perfectly good question).

Comment: @Amadan A GPU's primary use is graphics on screen, but sometimes it's used for programming. A chair's primary use is sitting in, but sometimes [it's used as a racecar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLIi9LM3KYM) and CUDA's primary use is programming though I'm sure it's sometimes used for other things. See the difference?

Comment: @ivarni Come on, this is not a serious (or fair) comparison. GPUs started out as graphics cards; today, they're basically specialised vector processing hardware, that is equally good at drawing stuff and at e.g. training a neural network. It's just that more individuals use it for gaming, whereas most people don't know how to train a NN. That does not mean GPU is a "chair being used as a racecar". When chairs are able to do 400 km/h but most people still use them for sitting in place, _then_ you can give me that argument.

Comment: One more thing that caught my eye: "Especially because there are a lot of other sites on the web that already provide that data.". Please provide one that gives insight into _CUDA-related_ (not gamer-oriented) performance details on two GTX 1080 vs a single RTX 2080. If there are "a lot of other sites", it should be easy to link _one_, no?

Comment: @Amadan You can basically look up every 1080 vs 2080 comparison. Since there is no SLI support for CUDA, the performance gain of having two cards vs one card depends entirely how you distribute the work between the two cards. When all calculations are independent, then you get exactly 2x the speed of one card. Cuda Cores and Memory Speed are stated on the NVIDIA product site for each card.

Comment: I didn't know that. More importantly, _the asker_ didn't know that ("I am not familiar with the hardware side of programming"). Would it not have made more sense for you (or anyone) to have answered that to @mathguy, rather than to me? Even if it were just in a comment along with a close vote? (I tagged him, so maybe he'll see it here now.)

Comment: Hey everyone, the asker here. What I want to do with the GPU is the following:

1) transfer a large 3D Numpy array(array.shape = (120000,700,100)) from python to the GPU, each element is of dtype = float64

2)do a few vectorized operations on this large array

3) return the said array back to the Python

Since GPU seems to play a big role in this, this question can only be accurately answered by people who know both the GPU very well and Numpy/Numba very well.

Comment: @mathguy: You can't use SLI for CUDA. Unless you are manually making sure that the work is split to the two graphiccards, you won't be able to utilize two cards at the same time. But as I said above: SO is the wrong place to ask for hardware recommendations.

Comment: @BDL your reply answers my question directly(you said unless I can split the work, utilizing two gpu won't be possible right, so that only leaves one choice: go with one good gpu rather than two normal gpu). I wish more people would've at least tried to understand my concern rather than simply flag for close in SO

Comment: @Amadan No words can express my huge thanks, without you raising the awareness to the problem, I wouldn't have found out the answer I am looking for.